# Filter object or array

Tags: json, jq

I would like to list all the Ids and roles in a given json but where there  is only a single role, rather than an array of 1 it provides it as an object, so if I run "[]?" I get the error Cannot index string with string "Name".

Extract (example.json):

```
{
  "Person": [
    {
      "Roles": {
        "Role": {
          "@Id": "1",
          "Name": "Job1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Roles": {
        "Role": [
          {
            "@Id": "2",
            "Name": "Job2"
          },
          {
            "@Id": "3",
            "Name": "Job3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I hoped this may work:

```
jq -r . | '.Roles.Role[]?>.@Id + "," + .Roles.Role[]?>.Name'
```

This is the output I'd like (so I can pipe to a csv)

```
1,Job1
2,Job2
3,Job3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following produces the CSV shown below. It would be easy to tweak the program to remove the double-quotation marks, etc.

```
.Person[]
| .Roles.Role
| if type == "array" then .[] else . end
| [.["@Id"], .Name]
| @csv
```

### Output

```
"1","Job1"
"2","Job2"
"3","Job3"
```

### Adding the index in .Person

```
.Person
| range(0; length) as $ix
| .[$ix]
| .Roles.Role
| if type == "array" then .[] else . end
| [$ix, .["@Id"], .Name]
| @csv
```

Comment: Thank you, that works a treat! Do you know how would I also print the Person[Index]?